# Spark: Dimensions mismatch error with RDD[LabeledPoint] union

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I would ideally like to do the following:
In essence, what I want to do is for my dataset that is RDD[LabeledPoint], I want to control the ratio of positive and negative labels.

```
val training_data: RDD[LabeledPoint] = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(spark, "training_data.tsv")
```

This dataset has both cases and controls included in it. I want to control the ratio of cases to controls (my dataset is skewed). So I want to do something like sample training_data such that the ratio of cases to controls is 1:2 (instead of 1:500 say).

I was not able to do that therefore, I separated the training data into cases and controls as below and then was trying to combine them later using union operator, which gave me the Dimensions mismatch error.

I have two datasets (both in Libsvm format):

```
val positives: RDD[LabeledPoint] = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(spark, "positives.tsv")
val negatives: RDD[LabeledPoint] = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(spark, "negatives.tsv")
```

I want to combine these two to form training data. Note both are in libsvm format.

```
training = positives.union(negatives)
```

When I use the above training dataset in model building (such as logistic regression) I get error since both positives and negatives can have different number of columns/dimensions. I get this error: "Dimensions mismatch when merging with another summarizer" Any idea how to handle that?

In addition, I also want to do samplings such as

```
positives_subset = positives.sample()
```

Comment: If these have different dimensions how do you want to use them to build a single model? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just updated the question with more details. Looking forward to hearing your thoughts.

Comment: It shouldn't affect dimensions. Each vector should represent a single observation (row if you prefer).  Also, Spark provides tools for stratified sampling.

Comment: Agreed, that is why I was doing the union, however, unfortunately that does not work. Stratified sampling is only with PairedRDD, not sure if  it can work with RDD[LabeledPoint]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this in the following way:

```
  def create_subset(training: RDD[LabeledPoint], target_label: Double, sampling_ratio: Double): RDD[LabeledPoint] = {
    val training_filtered = training.filter { case LabeledPoint(label, features) =>  (label == target_label) }
    val training_subset = training_filtered.sample(false, sampling_ratio)
    return training_subset
  }
```

Then calling the above method as:

```
  val positives = create_subset(training, 1.0, 1.0)
  val negatives_sampled = create_subset(training, 0.0, sampling_ratio)
```

Then you can take the union as:

```
  val training_subset_double = positives.union(negatives_double)
```

and then I was able to use the training_subset_double for model building.